# Azure AD B2C for UWP requires API scopes but I don't have any

Tags: azure, authentication, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Azure AD B2C** with **UWP** [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp) on GitHub requires some optional steps as described on the GitHub readme which asks for us to create a **web API** in **step 4** and hence use **API scopes** for that web API in the code written in **app.xaml.cs**

```cs
public static string[] ApiScopes = { "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/demoapi/demo.read" };
```

**Problem :** I don't have a **backend API** for my project yet and I don't want to make a traditional web API for my project, I will be using **Azure Functions** for a serverless API.

But the Sign In button leads to getting **authenticationToken** with following method:

```cs
authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(App.ApiScopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PublicClientApp.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, App.Authority);
```

As you can see above that **App.ApiScopes** are provided here which is a must parameter in this method, if I provide a list of string[] with an empty string only here, I am able to login but I don't see any token in the output in my UWP UI.

So how can I bypass this API scope problem and have a working sample for myself, or do I have to create a **web API** for some kind of security reason I mean is that a mandatory part?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use your app's *client_id* as the scope in order to get a token issued to itself.**

This approach is fine if you want to tightly couple your client and API, however if you end up having multiple Azure functions, multiple clients and don't want all clients to be able to call all functions, you'll need to start splitting up their app registrations and define scopes accordingly.

Comment: I tried providing client id as api scope and got this exception : "api does not accept client id as use provided scope"

Comment: Did I miss any step ?